# Compiling Python module for android

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I have a Python/Kivy application I'm trying to compile for Android, using Buildozer. It uses a third party module (freeswitchESL) which is imported in the code thus:

```
from freeswitchESL import ESL
```

Everything compiles ok, but the app crashes as soon as it runs. Looking through the logcat the device is returning, it seems to be running into problems finding the internal name for the module:

```
I/python  (11682):  ImportError: No module named _ESL
```

I can't figure out how to correct this. I've tried this sort of thing in buildozer.spec:

```
source.include_patterns = freeswitchESL/*
```

But to no avail. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? It's the first time I've tried compiling for a mobile device, and it's definitely not as straightforward as I had hoped ;)

Comment: The obvious guess is that it needs compilation, in which case you'd need to make a compilation recipe for the module.

Answer (score 0):

"requirements" section in buildozer.spec is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Putting you additional files in a folder and putting a `__init__.py` there can do the trick.Check this app for a clue https://github.com/tito/android-demo
However if the app is 3rd party and you don't have the .py files for those
probably you've to think differently.For example numpy is supported so if used
in requirement we need to add numpy in following way in buildozer.spec

```
requirements = kivy,numpy
```

But if you use pandas,scipy or scikit-learn those are not supported and hence can't be added like that.An alternative is to implement that function in numpy or pure python,or create a recipe.